# Doing 64bit addition with 2 high 32bit integers and 2 low 32bit integers. Are there more efficient ways of getting the carry bit?

Tags: bit-manipulation, hlsl, carryflag

Let's say that A and B are my lower 32bit integers, and T is a 32bit integer that I want to represent the carry from adding A and B.  I threw together some quick logic to get T:

```
T = (A >> 1) + (B >> 1);
T += A & B & 1;
T >>= 31;
```

It works, but I'm not a huge fan of the number of operations required to do this (3 right shifts, 2 adds, 2 ands).  I'd really appreciate input from some bit-twiddling experts on how to make this cleaner/more efficient.  Thanks!

For my current problem, I'm limited to what I can do in HLSL.  I wouldn't mind SM4 and SM5 specific solutions, but I'm also open to something that would work in general.

Answer (score 1):

Would the technique here work: [Efficient 128-bit addition using carry flag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6659414/10396)?

```
S = A + B;
T = (S < A);
```

I am assuming a comparison results in 1 or 0 like in C.  If not, add `?1:0` to the end of the statement.

Comment: I really like the idea, but it doesn't seem to work in my case.  Good to know that there are ideas for it other than my mess above, however.

Comment: I don't know about about HLSL but if it's a Turing-complete language then obviously it would support things like `T = (S < A) ? 1 : 0` or `if (S < A) T = 1; else T = 0;`