# 64-bit time_t in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, 64-bit, time-t, year2038

I have compiled kernel 3.19.1 but still have a problem with `time_t`. Just a simple program with `cout << sizeof (time_t);` gives size of 4 bytes, not 8 bytes as was my intention.

Should I switch on a particular option during make menuconfig?

Answer (score 6):

64-bit time support on 32-bit Linux was [first introduced in the **5.1 kernel**](https://lwn.net/Articles/776427/) so if you're older than that, sorry. Because changing the return type of the old system calls breaks old applications, new [`*time64` syscalls](https://lwn.net/ml/linux-kernel/20190110172216.313063-12-arnd@arndb.de/) had to be added instead. Check [this table](https://fedora.juszkiewicz.com.pl/syscalls.html) and you'll see that those syscalls are only available on 32-bit platforms.

Now if you're writing code for 32-bit systems you can call `clock_gettime64` directly (from inline assembly, or from C with [`syscall()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) function) to get the current time. However after that you're completely on your own. For full *userspace* support you must be on **Linux 5.6 or higher** along with musl 1.2+ or glibc 2.32+. Just rebuild your code and `time_t` will become 64-bit long

> - All user space must be compiled with a 64-bit `time_t`, which will be supported in the coming musl-1.2 and glibc-2.32 releases, along with installed kernel headers from linux-5.6 or higher.
> - Applications that use the system call interfaces directly need to be ported to use the `time64` syscalls added in linux-5.1 in place of the existing system calls. This impacts most users of `futex()` and `seccomp()` as well as programming languages that have their own runtime environment not based on libc.
>
> https://lkml.org/lkml/2020/1/29/355?anz=web

For more information read

- [Approaching the kernel year-2038 end game](https://lwn.net/Articles/776435/)
- Discussion on how to solve [Y2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem): [2038 is closer than it seems](https://lwn.net/Articles/599580/)
- [64-bit time symbol handling in the GNU C Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/64_002dbit-time-symbol-handling.html)
- [glibc Y2038 Proofness Design](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Y2038ProofnessDesign)
- [Change time_t and clock_t to 64 bit](https://lwn.net/Articles/598408/)

Answer (score 1):

Currently `time_t` is just `long` in kernel: see [__kernel_time_t](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/posix_types.h#L88) type definition. So if `long` type on your CPU is 32-bit long, `time_t` also is 32-bit long. Basically, if you have 32-bit CPU -- `long` type on your system is also 32-bit long. If you have 64-bit CPU -- `long` type will be 64-bit long.

If you need your own 64-bit type -- just use `long long`. If you want kernel time API to work with 64-bit long type as `time_t` -- it's a little harder (implies changing kernel sources). For example take a look [here](http://git.rocketboards.org/?p=linux-socfpga-next.git;a=blobdiff;f=include/uapi/asm-generic/posix_types.h;h=3f0e613c6233498461f5475b32c5b9610f9eed57;hp=fe74fccf18db75742d240151ec358049861b7406;hb=22ae3e4bcb6c136d2d815c4da180319d8a3ad070;hpb=38583f095c5a8138ae2a1c9173d0fd8a9f10e8aa). Also you may be interested in reading next links:

[1] [patchset: "Change time_t and clock_t to 64 bit"](http://lwn.net/Articles/598408/)

[2] [Is there any way to get 64-bit time_t in 32-bit program in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361651/is-there-any-way-to-get-64-bit-time-t-in-32-bit-program-in-linux)

[3] [What is ultimately a time_t typedef to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to)

### UPDATE

Regarding building issues (with `__divdi3` etc.) after changing `time_t` to `long long`.

Now that you have changed `time_t` size to 64-bits, any code that uses `time_t` will try to use 64-bit operations. `__divdi3` means: **div**ision operation on **d**ouble **i**ntegers. **3** stands for count of operands (like `1 = 2 / 3`). See [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Integer-library-routines.html#Integer-library-routines) for details. So this operation obviously hasn't implemented for your platform. You should either implement it by yourself (in kernel code) or use implementation from `gcc` somehow. Next links should help you:

[1] [__udivdi3 undefined. Howto find code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063585/udivdi3-undefined-howto-find-code)

[2] [divdi3 division used for long long by gcc on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448343/divdi3-division-used-for-long-long-by-gcc-on-x86)

[3] [Where to find udivdi3 and umoddi3 in gcc?](http://embdev.net/topic/129575)

Comment: I'd rather use [`int64_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) because I know it will be 64 bit all the time without even thinking about it.  It is only available since C99, though.

Comment: As I understand you are developing kernel. In kernel you always have [int64_t](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/types.h#L113) defined in `include/linux/types.h`, so you don't have to use C99+. Just use `#include <linux/types.h>`, or it can be even included implicitly via other headers (it usually does).

Comment: I can change operators like % or / on do_div() or similar macros, but I'm not sure if that task is worth doing. Let's take a first function with build error - time_to_tm() - there's a lot of long types inside (not long long), it calls for static long math_div(long a, long b) (once again not long long). So a lot of other functions should be rebuild. Also functions from glibc should be rebuild - time(), ctime(), mktime(), etc. Last, but no least - system ABI is affected. According to http://lwn.net/Articles/607741/ we need patience :)

Comment: You shouldn't **replace** (or change) operators in code. You just need to **implement** a few operations like `__divdi3`. But you are right,it still would imply changing all related code in user-space. So best option is to use available 32-bit implementation for now (it will be still valid till 2038) and wait for kernel developers to change it at some point in future.