# How to store decimal value of 40 digits?

Tags: c

I have made a C program of 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 +......... 2^64. My problem is that such a big value is not being stored. Which data type should I use?
Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
   int i;
   int number=2;
   int total=1;
   int power=64;
   int totalSum=1;
   for(i=1;i<=power;)
   {
      total=total*number;
      totalSum=totalSum+total;
      i++;
   }

   printf("%d\n",total);
   printf("Sum=%d",totalSum);
}
```

Kindly can you please tell me that which type of data type should I use i C language

Comment: Please refere to this [link in stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252896/how-to-store-a-very-long-integer-value-in-a-c-program-for-an-exam-98474737475)

Comment: Look for a bigint implementation. Here's a C example. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20783/a-small-biginteger-implementation-i-wrote-in-c-my-first-decent-c-program-plea

Comment: uint128_t is not enough, 10^40 is a bit greater than 2^132, so at least 133 bits are needed.

Comment: A few comments on the posted code: 1) the return type from main() is always 'int', never 'void'.   2) For readability and ease of understanding, please consistently indent the code.  3) the 'i++' should be the third parameter of the 'for()' statement  4) you probably should read about the operators: '+=' and '*='  5) the variables 'total' and 'totalsum' will have to be from the bignum library,  'int' is way too small

Comment: Implement your own arithmetic functions for big integers. Store the digits in a char array of std::string.