# Malloc() to create a new size for integers for use with math - Guidance needed

Tags: c, memory, malloc

My goal is to create a integer type with a bigger size than 4 bytes, or 8 if I use long. I tried malloc  to try and give more bytes in the memory for a bigger integer, but it still broke on the 31st iteration (gave a negative number). here's my code:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 31; //(normally an int can do up to 30 without going negative so this is my test number)
    int i;

    int *bigNum = NULL;
    bigNum = malloc((sizeof(int)*2));
    *bigNum = 1;
    for (i=0; i<x; i++) {
          *bigNum = *bigNum * 2;
          printf("%d \n", *bigNum);
    }
    free(bigNum);
}
```

Output:

```
2
4
...
..
...
1073741824
-2147483648
```

Comment: Integer overflow. What's `INT_MAX` on your system?

Comment: _it still broke on the 31st iteration_ ....you have a **very good an crystal** evidence of what is going on.......

Comment: There's really no need to use `malloc` and dynamic allocation and pointers here. Just defining your `bigNum` variable like a normal variable would work just as well (or just like what you have now anyway).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store a very long integer value in a C program for an exam :- 98474737475747374739399](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252896/how-to-store-a-very-long-integer-value-in-a-c-program-for-an-exam-98474737475)

Comment: As for what's happening, you have an *overflow*. While overflowing a signed integer (like you do) is technically *undefined behavior* what actually happens is something that depends on how negative numbers are represented on your computer. Read about [*two's complement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) for more information about that.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you'll allocate more memory for a type.. It is still a 4-byte `int` and it would overflow as your code demonstrates. To store bigger numbers you need to create your own type with underlying logic or use some library like BigInt

Comment: P.P - the INT_MAX is 2147483647
Raw nN - sorry about that, will be more careful next time
LPs - your sarcasm actually made me laugh lmao!!

Also thanks for everyones comments really gave me a better insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dereferencing an `int *` gives you an `int` no matter *how* much extra memory you allocate for it.

If you want a dat type able to hold more information, try a `long` (although the guarantee is that it will be *at least* as big as an `int`).

If you want to handle integers beyond what your implementation provides, use a bignum library, like [MPIR](http://mpir.org/).

Comment: I am interested in the logic behind a bignum library, how do they produce these datatypes?

Comment: @SteveSlayo Any integer is an array of bytes, where the first byte values 0 to 2^8 - 1, second byte is values 2^8 to 2^16 -1 and so on. Formally something like `2^(0*8) <= b0 - 1 <= 2^(1*8)`, `2^(1*8) <= b1 - 1 <= 2^(2*8)`, ... , `2^(n*8) <= bn - 1 <= 2^((n+1)*8)`.

Comment: @Rand, if only I had an answer for that. Wait a minute, I *do:* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218149/arbitrary-precision-arithmetic-explanation/1218185#1218185 :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo you cheeky bugger. That was an amazing write up, completely answered my question, thx!

Answer (score 1):

Although you have allocated more memory for your integer, no other part of the system knows this, including:

- the compiler doesn't know this;
- the CPU chip doesn't know this.
- printf doesn't know this.

So all calculations are just carried out using the native int size.

Note that you can't tell the CPU chip you use larger integers; it is a physical/design limitation of the chip.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> goal is to create a integer type with a bigger size

To handle multi-`int` integers, code also needs supporting functions for each basic operation:

```
int main(void) {
    int x = 31;

    RandBigNum *bigNum = RandBigNum_Init();
    RandBigNum_Assign_int(bigNum, 1);
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
      RandBigNum_Muliply_int(bigNum, 2);
      RandBigNum_Print(bigNum);
      printf(" \n");
    }
```

Now, how might implement all this?  Many approaches.

Below is a *simply*, incomplete and untested one.  It is not necessarily a *good* approach, but to present an initial idea of the details needed to accomplish a *big number* library.

```
//  Numbers are all positive.  The first array element is the size of the number
typedef unsigned RandBigNum;

#define RandBigNum_MAXP1 (UINT_MAX + 1ull)

RandBigNum *RandBigNum_Init(void) {
  return calloc(1, sizeof *RandBigNum);
}

void RandBigNum_Muliply_int(RandBigNum *x, unsigned scale) {
  unsigned carry = 0;
  for (unsigned i = 1; i <= x[0]; i++) {
    unsigned long long product = 1ull * x[i] * scale + carry;
    x[i] = product % RandBigNum_MAXP1;
    carry *= product / RandBigNum_MAXP1;
  }
  if (carry) {
    unsigned n = x[0] + 2;
    x = realloc(x, sizeof *x * n); // re-alloc check omitted
    x[x[0]] = carry;
    x[0]++;
  }
}

// many other functions
```