# atoll() doesn't return the correct number

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function that takes a string, converts it to a number and prints its first factor in the format: n=p*q

the number I give is: **1718944270642558716715**
But it prints **9223372036854775807**

and it's not only wrong while printing but when I see the calculation. The number is supposed ot have a factor 5, but my code gives me 7. which means that atoll() gives the wrong number.

How to fix this?

```
int factorize(char *buffer)
{
    long long int num, i;

    num = atoll(buffer);
    for (i = 2; i < num / 2 + 1; i++)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            printf("%lli=%lli*%lli\n", num, num / i, i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

I tried many types unsigned int, u_int32_t, but I still get the wrong number.

Comment: also tried `%lld` same problem.

Comment: `2^70` < `1718944270642558716715` < `2^71`. Your number needs 71 bits.

Comment: @pmg how to handle such a big number in C?

Comment: I see that `long long` has this range: **-9,223,372,036,854,775,808** to **9,223,372,036,854,775,807** and my number is still within that range!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you store an arbitrarily large integer value in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252896/how-do-you-store-an-arbitrarily-large-integer-value-in-memory)

Comment: Don't show code with line numbers. Show the verbatim code you compile.

Comment: Read closely the "Return Value" section from the [atoll documentation](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoll/)

Comment: @RaymondChen How am I going to use the number (math operations) if I save it as a structure?

Comment: No, your number is not within that range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` has 19 digits (max signed 64bit integer)
- `1,718,944,270,642,558,716,715` has 22 digits

So your claim

> I see that long long has this range: -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to
> 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 and my number is still within that range

Is definitely wrong. Your number does not fit in 64bit integer (it does not matter if it is signed or not)

Your number will fit into 128 integers.

Here you have a very simple implementation (not handling negative numbers)

```
__int128 atoll128(char *str)
{
    __int128 result = 0;
    while(*str)
    {
        result *= 10;
        result += *str - '0';
        str++;
    }
    return result;
}

void print128(__int128 x)
{
    if(x) print128(x / 10);
    else return;
    printf("%d", (int)(x % 10));
}

int factorize(char *buffer)
{
    __int128 num, i;

    num = atoll128(buffer);
    for (i = 2; i < (num / 2 + 1); i++)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
        print128(num); printf(" ");
        print128(num / i); printf(" ");
        print128(i); printf("\n");
        break;
        }
    }
    return (0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    factorize("1718944270642558716715");
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. That's really helpful.
How do you print `__int128` type? `%d` won't work.

Comment: @modernAlchemist https://stackoverflow.com/q/11656241/589924

Comment: @modernAlchemist you need to write your own function as I did in this example

Comment: The simplest way I found to print without needing to print an `__int128` type, is using a character `b = x % 10 + '0'` and then priting the character.

Comment: Corner oops: `print128(0)` prints nothing.

Comment: `for (i = 2; i <= num/i; i++)` much faster than `for (i = 2; i < (num / 2 + 1); i++)` for large primes.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica good spot

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it is something only to demonstrate how to use int128. negativbe numbers or zero support is left to OP :)

Answer (score 1):

To handle *signed* 128-bit integer printing, including negatives:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// INT128_MIN --> -1.701411...e+38
//                     sign digits   \0
#define I128_STR_SIZE (1 + (1 + 38) + 1)
int print128(__int128 x) {
  char buf[I128_STR_SIZE]; 
  char *ptr = buf + I128_STR_SIZE - 1;  // Point to last element.
  *ptr = '\0';

  char sign;
  if (x < 0) {
    sign = '-';
  } else {
    x = -x;
    sign = 0;
  }

  // Now only work with x <= 0.
  do {
    *--ptr = (char) ('0' - (int) (x % 10));
    x /= 10;
  } while (x);

  if (sign) {
    *--ptr = '-';
  }
  return fputs(ptr, stdout);
}
```